# Kafka streams fails to send messages to dynamically created topics when auto.register.schemas=false

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Kafka Streams dynamically creates auxiliary topics for operations such as `repartition()` or KTable joins, and sends messages using the configured default serializers.
When `auto.register.schemas=true` (the default setting), an Avro schema is registered when Kafka Streams sends a message.
But when `auto.register.schemas=false`, Kafka Streams errors with "Subject not found" (as discussed in [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260163/do-i-need-to-register-schema-for-kafka-stream-changelog-topic-under-schema-regis#comment112207297_63301930)).

The [Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_onprem_tutorial.html#auto-schema-registration) is silent on the matter, but is this the expected behaviour?  Or is this a bug in [avro4k-kafka-serializer](https://github.com/thake/avro4k-kafka-serializer) (I've yet to try with the built-in [`SpecificAvroSerializer`](https://github.com/thake/avro4k-kafka-serializer))?  If necessary I'll create a minimal example that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the following:

1. The dynamic topic is created. What happens is Kafka Streams asks the broker to create the topic with the right name for your application.
2. At some point you decide to write to that topic, meaning you start publishing messages. What happens at that point is KafkaStreams attempts to fetch the schema from Avro Schema Registry. If it fails to find a schema matching the subject (the subject is determined based on your serde configuration). It will attempt to register the schema. However in your case auto.register.schema is set to false, so no registration attempt is made. As there is no schema an error is thrown.

How to fix this:
Before starting your application register your schema via REST API of schema registry (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html).

If you don't have your avro schem in an *.avsc file, you can easily generate it:

```
ReflectData.get().getSChema(YourClass.class).toString();
```